# Saving current user name(logged) into Form database ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am newbie in ASP.NET. Is there a possible way to save the current logged user into the form database when the form is submitted?

(i.e) When multiple registered users enter a form and click save their user name is saved into the contents of form database.

I had googled it but couldn't find related topics (maybe I used the wrong keywords). If methods are available kindly suggest link.

**[Edit]**

I have used asp.net identity for authentication.

My current code for save

```
public ActionResult NewPR()
    {
        var depts = _context.Depts.ToList();
        var currencytypes = _context.Currencytypes.ToList();

        var viewModel = new NewPRViewModel
        {   
            PRview = new PRview(),
            Currencytypes = currencytypes,   
        };
        return View("NewPR", viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(PRview prview)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var viewModel = new NewPRViewModel
            {
                PRview = prview,
                Currencytypes = _context.Currencytypes.ToList()    
            };


            return View("NewPR", viewModel);
        }
        if (prview.Id == 0)
            _context.PRviews.Add(prview);
        else
        {  
            var prviewInDb = _context.PRviews.Single(c => c.Id == prview.Id);
            prviewInDb.SupplierName = prview.SupplierName;
            prviewInDb.Brand = prview.Brand;
            prviewInDb.Qty = prview.Qty;
            prviewInDb.Unitprice = prview.Unitprice;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "PRview");
    }
```

Comment: What does your form save function look like? Can you normally get the current user? If so what does that code look like? It's very difficult to give advice based on the information you've given.

Comment: You should probably add more detail like what have you used for authentication asp.net identity or your own custom authentication?It's difficult to answer based on your provided info.

Comment: @Lex I havent tried including user name into database but have edited my question with the save code i used. Kindly advise in detail on including logged user into form data submission DB.

Comment: @SumitBhattarai I used the default asp.net identity